# Dumpbin headers for many files

Tags: 64-bit, dumpbin

I want to check whether all my dlls and libs within a project were built for x64 using

```
dumpbin /headers *.obj | findstr machine
```

which outputs a list of e.g. `8664 machine (x64)`. How can I print the filename for each listed file? Or do I have to extract filenames into a separate textfile before to go with a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long look I found the solution for my problem

```
FOR /F %i IN ('DIR /B 2^>nul *.obj') DO (
    echo | set /P=%i:
    dumpbin /headers %i | findstr machine
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`dumpbin /headers *.obj | findstr "machine Dump"` will print the "Dump of file ...." line and the machine type line.

From the `findstr` help

> Use spaces to separate multiple search strings unless the argument is
>   prefixed with /C.  For example, 'FINDSTR "hello there" x.y' searches
>   for "hello" or "there" in file x.y.  'FINDSTR /C:"hello there" x.y'
>   searches for "hello there" in file x.y.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: no problem.  Next time if you make your question more explicit about what you are looking for, such as how do I print "filename:  machine", you'll get better answers.

Comment: @jcopenha - looking at the edit history, the only thing that changed on the question were the tags. Perhaps I'm mis-reading his request, bit it seems to me he was clear enough in his question when he asked how to print the file being operated upon.

Comment: @jww His request is for filenames and machine types. The output of my command generates that. In his comment he clarifies saying he wants "filename: machine". Which is a refinement of the format of the output. If you run the accepted answer and my answer you get all of the same information. the only difference is final format which wasn't specified in the original question.